# Deno not respecting types in typescript functions

Tags: node.js, typescript, tsc, deno

This is a sample index.ts file. As you can see my IDE gives error when a string is passed as an argument.

[image]

Also typescript compiler gives error when using `tsc index.ts`.

[image]

But surprisingly, when using `deno run index.ts`, the answer comes out as 210, and no error occurs.

[image]

Can anyone please explain me why is deno not giving any error when using it to run typescript.
For easier reproduction of the bug, here is my typescript code

```js
function add(a: number, b: number): number {
  const c: number = a + b;
  return c;
}

const num: number = 10;
console.log(add('2', num));
```

Comment: Typescript does stricter checks than Javascript does.

Comment: The file is indeed a typescript file, that is why when I run `tsc index.ts` it does not compile to javascript.

Comment: Yes, but when you 'run' this typescript file it doesn't do a full typecheck, it quickly emits javascript and runs the javascript under the hood.

Comment: With Deno, you don't need `tsc` at all (because it's built-in). You can type-check your code using `deno check index.ts`, and run it (without type-checking) using `deno run index.ts`, or type-check first and only run if it type-checking passes using `deno run --check index.ts`. (See the [docs](https://deno.land/manual@v1.32.5/getting_started/command_line_interface#runtime-flags).) Does that answer your question? If so, I can write it up as one — if not, what did I miss?

Answer (score 3):

Since Deno 1.23 you have to use `--check` flag if you want type-checking when using `deno run`

```
 --check[=<CHECK_TYPE>...]
            Type-check modules.
            
            Deno does not type-check modules automatically from v1.23 onwards.
            Pass this flag to enable type-checking or use the 'deno check'
            subcommand.
            
            If the value of '--check=all' is supplied, diagnostic errors from
            remote modules
            will be included.
```

Now if you run it, you'll get the error:

```
deno run --check index.ts
```

```
error: TS2345 [ERROR]: Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'.
console.log(add('2', num));
```